# Creating REST and SOAP endpoints for a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

I need a service with two endpoints.When I create service with 1 endpoint point, it works fine but when I add 2 endpoints it complains endpoint not found. 
Endpoint without address extension works fine but not with address ('download')
Here is my configuration:

**Server**

```
  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="MessageStreamBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"   httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>      

    <!--stream for video upload-->
    <binding name="httpLargeMessageStream"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967295"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                transferMode="Streamed">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <!--stream for video download-->
    <binding name="webHttpLargeMessageStream"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967295"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                transferMode="Streamed">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>



</bindings>
<services>

  <!--service for streamservice; video upload and download-->
  <service name="Trigger.CSSD.Service.Services.MediaService" behaviorConfiguration="MessageStreamBehavior" >
    <endpoint name="restDownloadHttpStream"
              behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" address="download"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpLargeMessageStream"
              contract="Trigger.CSSD.Service.Services.IDownloadMediaService" />


    <endpoint name="uploadHttpStream" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpLargeMessageStream"
             contract="Trigger.CSSD.Service.Services.IUploadMediaService" />

  </service>

</services>
```

**Client**

```
  <endpoint address="https://cssd-services:44300/MediaService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpStream"
        contract="MediaService.IUploadMediaService" name="basicHttpStream" />

  <endpoint address="https://cssd-services:44300/MediaService.svc/download" 
       binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpStream" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
       contract="MediaService.IDownloadMediaService" name="webHttpStream" />

</client>
```

**SERVICE**
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IDownloadMediaService
    {
        [OperationContract]
      //  [ContentType("video/mp4")]
      //  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "media/{name}")]
        Stream GetMedia(String name);

```
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadMediaService
{
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx
    [OperationContract]
    FileUploadResponseMessage UploadFile(FileUploadMessage message);
}
```

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class MediaService : IDownloadMediaService, IUploadMediaService
    {......
}

ANy suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to expose service at browser from this link - https://cssd-services:44300/MediaService.svc/download ?

Comment: no, thats my problem. I can read service if i use only rest endpoint without using address.

Comment: <service name="Trigger.CSSD.Service.Services.MediaService" behaviorConfiguration="MessageStreamBehavior" >
        <endpoint name="restDownloadHttpStream"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpLargeMessageStream"                  contract="Trigger.CSSD.Service.Services.IDownloadMediaService" />  
    CLIENT                       <endpoint address="https://cssd-services:44300/MediaService.svc" .../>  THIS WORKS

Comment: Could you please show the code snippet of mediaservice.svc file?

Comment: here's the mediaservice:

Comment: [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class MediaService : IDownloadMediaService, IUploadMediaService
    {
        public MediaService()
            : base()
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

            if (httpContext != null)
            {
                httpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;
            }
        }

Comment: public Stream GetMedia(String name)
        {
            var documentStoreService = IoC.Container.Resolve<IDocumentStoreService>();
            bool success;
            NHibernateSessionManager.OpenSession();
            NHibernateSessionManager.BeginTransaction();

            var stream = documentStoreService.GetVideoStream(name, out success);

            NHibernateSessionManager.CommitTransaction();
            NHibernateSessionManager.CloseSession();
            return stream;

Comment: I am new here, how can i add whole snippet? it has word restriction

Comment: Could you please add 'WebHttp' tag in config file for behaviorConfiguration of download and check it please